# Optimizing a list's search

Tags: python, search, optimization

I need to do a search in a list in an optimal way. Basicaly, if any element on the list is between Vmin and Vmax, and is a number (sometimes the procedure produces results that aren't numbers :/), I need to evaluate the loss (I have a function to do this). Otherwise, I give it a huge loss, like 10**10. Can you help me to optimize this search? I changed the structure to a list() because it is originaly a tuple, and i don't know how to manipulate this structure :/

```
def losses():
    Tensoes = list(objeto.get_AllNodeVpu())
    Lim = 0
    for i in Tensoes:
        if (i <= Vmin) or (i >= Vmax):
            Lim += 1
        if (np.isnan(i) == True):
            Lim += 1

    if (Lim == 0)
        loss = objeto.get_circuit_total_losses()
    else:
       loss = 10**10        

    return loss
```

Comment: At this stage in your computer programming education, you shouldn't worry too much about optimization. You need to learn about analyzing algorithms with Big-Oh notation to understand where possible optimizations are. You also need to learn about using a profiler to measure how long sections of your code take to run.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll look for it :D

Comment: I was looking for something that can help me, and I think that my question is more about a "pythonic way of do this kind of search"

Answer (score 0):

Is this Python? You should tag it then.

You are not doing a search here; you are processing every element of your list to check if it is out of bounds.

Is your list sorted? Then you can check only its first and last elements. But if you have to sort it - it will be more expensive then your current implementation.

P.S. You start with `It's me again` , but your status shows that THIS is your first post :)

APPENDED:
Well, you don't need to loop after you found first "invalid" element. I don't know Python, but should be something like:

```
def losses() :
    Tensoes = list(objeto.get_AllNodeVpu())
    for i in Tensoes :
        if np.isnan(i) == True or i <= Vmin or i >= Vmax :
            return 10 * *10

    return objeto.get_circuit_total_losses()
```

Comment: Tagged, thanks for the tip, and yes, second post. The first was about random strings... So, no, the list isn't sorted, but I don't need to sort. The list a set o node voltages and I need to verify if all the nodes are between the limits.